# Merge git branch to make intermediary results available to others

Tags: git

I'm often facing the same question but can't decide on what's a good practice here.

Say we're a couple of developers adding features to the *dev* branch (with branches *feature_1*, *feature_2*, ...) and merging them into *dev* when they're ready. (All of these branches are pushed to *origin* be it only for backup reasons.) Now I've implemented a basic version of *feature_1*, I'll still make it better but it's already working and others want to rebase the features they're developing on mine.

What would you do?

1. Have them rebase their *feature_x* on *feature_1*. It sounds bad to me because later on I might merge *feature_1* into *dev* — potentially creating a merge commit — and then I'm not sure what happens when they'll want to merge their *feature_x* in *dev* (which by then will most likely have other commits too).
2. Merge *feature_1* into *dev*, so that they can rebase their *feature_x* on *dev*. But then what do I do to keep working on *feature_1*?

   1. Simply continue working on *feature_1*? I'm not sure that's a proper way to do that because it's been merged (especially regarding tidiness of the git history).
   2. Delete *feature_1* and recreate a new branch with the same name from there? I can't come up with a better branch name than the one I already had: it's just the continuation.
   3. Create a new branch *feature_1_b* or something like that. That sounds messy to me, and nobody will know what I mean with "*_b*".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to simply merge and then continue working on feature_1? Sorry, but I do not understand your concern regarding tidiness here

Comment: I'm not exactly sure either. It's probably my understanding of branches that is flawed. Your comment goes in the same direction as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for something along the lines of your second choice:

If part of `feature_1` is ready (and by ready I especially mean that it does not break the application), I'd merge it in develop (following a "commit often, merge often" workflow), so that anybody working from develop can have access to it.

Then, once `feature_1` is merged, I'd then rebase it on top of `develop` (which is effectively the same as deleting the branch `feature_1` and recreate it on top of `develop`) and work on it from there.

Regarding your choice 1, I'd not recommend to have people base their work on top of your feature branch, as you might want to rework your branch, reorder the commits, amend them and so on. I'd consider someone else's feature branch (pushed or not) as private and potentially unstable, and would not touch it, nor base my work on it.